# C++ union-initialization by immediate vs. initialization by variable

Tags: c++

Why is this in C++ allowed ...

```
union u
{
    double d = 1.0;
    long long ll;
};
```

... but not this ...

```
double v = 1.0;
union u
{
    double d = v;
    long long ll;
};
```

MSVC and g++ accept the first but not the latter.

Comment: I compiled on g++ 14 GCC 9.1.0 and the second one works fine.

Comment: Second one works on clang++ (Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)).  Compiled with `clang++ -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-padded -Wno-c99-compat -pedantic -fsanitize=undefined,null -std=c++17`

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/JiWM_r)

Comment: What errors are you getting from MSVC and g++?

Comment: Next time please specify _versions_ of your compiler and of C++. There have been many of both.

Answer (score 1):

[It *is* allowed](https://godbolt.org/z/JiWM_r), but [only since non-static data member initialisers were introduced in C++11](https://godbolt.org/z/dJk_ah). Older C++ Standards like C++98 don't accept it. Unless you are maintaining a project built in a legacy standard like C++98, try to avoid using those old standards.

Comment: Why do you recommend "not to use ancient standards". Are you asserting that the only reason they can't use the later source example is because they have their compiler set to an older standards comliance? Or are you suggesting not to use that syntax at all?

Comment: @RubyA.Rose Yes, the reason the code fails for the OP is that they are in C++98 mode.